# Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

guys i am using [jqgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCe1c.png)

and when i click on `saveAllRows` an error occurs which is `Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined` .. here is my code for that button

```
function saveAllRows(){
         var ids = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
        }
    }
```

and here is what i included

```js
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a Boostrap  and jqGrid Bootstrap CSS siles-->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/jquery.timepicker.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script> 
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/jquery.timepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/style.css" />
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

any help .. why that happens ??

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which JavaScript files you included and in which order?

Comment: update my question .. plz have a look

Comment: i am using  Guriddo jqGrid JS

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined

means that the string like `$.jgrid.defaults.errors.errcap`, `$.jgrid.locales["en-US"].errors.errcap` or `$.jgrid.regional.en.errors.errcap` (dependent from the version and the fork of jqGrid which you use) is undefined. The problem can't exist if you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) because the required strings for en-US locale are defined in `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. For example to use the latest free jqGrid 4.13.3 you need to include `ui.jqgrid.min.css` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.3/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.3/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```

which included all what you need.

If you use some old jqGrid, for example jqGrid 4.6 then **you have to include `grid.locale-en.js`**, which defines some language specific strings inclusive `$.jgrid.defaults.errors.errcap`. Then the list of included files should be the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still not saving date .. it gives me message undefined

Comment: @mermer: What do you tried? Do you tried to replace `grid.locale-en.js`, `ui.jqgrid.css` and `jquery.jqGrid.js` which you use currently with URLs to free jqGrid 4.13.3, which I posted? The message means **two problems**: 1) the changes can't be saved 2) the error message can't be displayed in the locale which you use. Do you have the demo online?

Comment: when i click on save all rows .. it saves all except the date .. a message gives me undefined pops out .. here is my code for the date

Comment: plz check the answer i posted

Comment: @mermer: Sorry, but you mix a lot of different problems together. 1) the usage of `datepicker` is wrong (you place the options of `datepicker` like `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'`, `showOn` and so on in wrong place). 2) in case of *error* the user should see no message about "undefined" variables. If the message is displayed then you included wrong `grid.locale-en.js` (from another version, which wrong URL etc) or you used wrong local option of jqGrid. The options depend on **version** and fork of jqGrid. Could you answer **which version** of jqGrid you use?

Comment: @mermer: Independent from your final choice of the version and the fork of jqGrid I suggest you to change (at least temporary) 2-3 lines of your current code to use free jqGrid 4.13.3 from CDN and verify that you will don't have any error messages with **undefined** 'errcap'. I remind you that Guriddo jqGrid is available with source code, but it can't be used for free (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). If you bought the product you should post your question to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js/help).

Comment: @mermer: http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/ contains **not your code**. Please read my last comments. If you want to try free jqGrid with Bootstrap then you need just add `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` option and optionally `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm), which uses bootstrap-datepicker. I want to repeat that **successful working with bootstrap datepicker is not your current question**. You question is: why one see the error message "Cannot read property 'errcap' of undefined" on saving error.

Comment: @mermer: To use stackoverflow you should understand it's rules. It's not a help forum where one will solves **your specific problems**. You should formulate your question so that it have some value for *another users/visitors*. Moreover your should formulate the problem so that it could be found during *searching*. Thus **you should try to separate multiple problems in short small problems**. If your current problem is displaying of wrong error message (with "'errcap' is undefined") then you should concentrates on the problem only *to help other people, who have the same problem*.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ label: 'Date', name: 'Date', width: 150 , "formatter":"date",
                           editable: true,
                           edittype:"custom",
                           editoptions: {
                               autoclose: true,
                               autoOpen: false,
                               format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                               orientation : 'auto bottom',
                               showOn: 'both',
                               formatoptions :{"srcformat":"Y-m-d", "newformat":"m/d/Y"},
                               dataInit : function (elem) {
                                  // $(elem).datepicker({autoclose: true});
                                   //$(elem).datepicker('hide');
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                      $(elem).datepicker({autoclose: true});
                                   },10);
                                   /*$(elem).on('changeDate', function(ev){
                                        $(this).datepicker('hide');
                                    });*/

                               },
                               custom_element: function(value, options) {
                                  var parts = value.split(' ');
                                var elemStr = '<div><input size="6" id="txt_' +'" value="' + parts[0] +
                                '" /><input type="button" size="5" value="..."/></div>';

                                  // return DOM element from jQuery object
                                  return $(elemStr)[0];
                              },
                              custom_value: function(elem) {
                                  var inputs = $("input", $(elem));
                                  var first = inputs.value;
                                  return first;
                              }
                           }
                       },
```

Comment: It's **not the answer on your question**. You should click on "edit" button below your question and modify the text of your question. One appends typically the text with **UPDATED:**, **UPDATED 1:** **UPDATED 2:**, ... and some additional information which could help to understand your original question.